# MapReduce error：The main class could not be found or loaded

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I use hadoop-3.2.2,A Hadoop cluster has just been configured. When using mapreduce to calculate PI, an error is reported
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :

I want to know the cause of the error and how to correct it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mapreduce execution logs are stored by YARN executors, not your hadoop jar command output. You can use CLI `yarn application logs` or use YARN UI to find real error (the `hadoop jar` command shows you `URL to track the job...`)

Hard to knit how to correct it without the actual error

> mapreduce to calculate PI

Spark can do this too. Why do you need mapreduce?

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi.py